# Blocked a frame with origin - Heroku and Node

Tags: javascript, heroku, cors

I am trying to deploy my first website - although I can use some JS to code locally, I have never deployed anything. In this case, I have built a scrapper to get data from a Brazilian newspaper, and organise it into a json file. That's working well locally, as I have deployed to Heroku.

The app is a Node app, using puppetteer to get the information from the webpage. I am rendering the output in the DOM, but that's just to me visualise what is working.

I have been receiving this error: "Blocked a frame with origin "https://folha-scrapper-117789299b68.herokuapp.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://www.herokucdn.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."

I am pretty sure this is a cross-origin issue.

here is the repository: https://github.com/luiz-flamorim/folha-scrapper.git

Can anyone give me a bit of guidance?

on the server side, I am using the following:

```
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors({
  origin: ["https://folha-scrapper-117789299b68.herokuapp.com","https://www.herokucdn.com/"]
}));
```

I expected that it would sort the CORS... but it hasn't.